# How to separate text within a cell of a google sheets by Capital Letter

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I need help splitting the text that I have in a cell within my Google Sheets spreadsheet.  The data I have is missing a space between each word that starts with a capital letter.  For example Cell A1 contains "BarbaraSmith"  I need a google script that will separate the contents in A1 to B1 and C1 where B1 will contain Barbara and C1 will contain Smith.

Thanks

Comment: var str="BarbaraSmith" ; var patt = new RegExp("[A-Z][^A-Z]*", "g");   str.match(patt);    This would give you those words in a array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for loop, check if letter is capital, then move all chars collected into words array.

```js
function splitWords(str) {
  const start = "A".charCodeAt(0);
  const end = "Z".charCodeAt(0);
  const words = [];

  let word = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const code = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (code >= start && code <= end) {
      if (word) {
        words.push(word);
        word = "";
      }
    }
    word = `${word}${str[i]}`;
  }
  words.push(word);
  return words;
}

console.log(splitWords("BarbaraSmith"));
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll give this a try as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link to see how to create a custom function 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function

Copy this code into that custom function

```
function CSepString(from) {
 var patt = new RegExp("[A-Z][^A-Z]*", "g");
 return [from.match(patt)];
}
```

come to the google sheet and use it like this

```
=CSepString(A1)
```

Comment: That works great.  Thank you for such a quick response.